# Why converting a Firestore querySnapshot into custom objects with compactMap returns empty although the querySnapshot contains documents?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flatmap

[Screenshot of a Firestore Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxLWd.png)

I am using Swift, Xcode and a Firestore database. 
I created a TableView and a Custom Object Class (MediumSample) with a dictionary and want to load my Firestore documents and show them in the TableView.

The documents (example in the screenshot) are loaded from Firestore correctly but the conversion into the object did not work. The list of objects returned from compactMap is always empty.

Here is my code snippets. It would be great, if someone has a hint on what is going wrong.

Custom Object Class (simplified):

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

protocol MediumSampleDocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String:Any])
}

struct MediumSample {

    var id: String
    var field_t: String
    var field_i: Int64
    var field_b1: Bool
    var field_b2: Bool
    var field_g: FirebaseFirestore.GeoPoint
    var field_d: Date
    var field_a: [String]
    var usecase: String


    var dictionary: [String:Any] {
         return [
             "id": id,
             "field_t": field_t,
             "field_i": field_i,
             "field_b1": field_b1,
             "field_b2": field_b2,
             "field_g": field_g,
             "field_d": field_d,
             "field_a": field_a,
             "usecase": usecase
         ]
     }

}

extension MediumSample: MediumSampleDocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        guard let id = dictionary ["id"] as? String,
        let field_t = dictionary ["field_t"] as? String,
        let field_i = dictionary ["field_i"] as? Int64,
        let field_b1 = dictionary ["field_b1"] as? Bool,
        let field_b2 = dictionary ["field_b2"] as? Bool,
        let field_g = dictionary ["field_g"] as? FirebaseFirestore.GeoPoint,
        let field_d = dictionary ["field_d"] as? Date,
        let field_a = dictionary ["field_a"] as? [String],
        let usecase = dictionary ["usecase"] as? String else {return nil}

        self.init (id: id, field_t: field_t, field_i: field_i, field_b1: field_b1, field_b2: field_b2, field_g: field_g, field_d: field_d, field_a: field_a, usecase: usecase)
    }

}
```

Declaration of the database and array and calling the loading function:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore

class MediumTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //MARK: Properties

    var db: Firestore!
    var mediumsamples = [MediumSample]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        db = Firestore.firestore()
        loadMediumSamples()

    }
```

Function for loading the Firestore documents to fill the Array:

```
    private func loadMediumSamples() {

               //run the Firestore query
               db.collection(Constants.MEDIUMS).whereField("usecase", isEqualTo: Constants.USECASE)
                   .getDocuments() { querySnapshot, err in
                       if let err = err {
                           print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                       } else {

                        //initialise an array of medium objects with Firestore data snapshots
                        self.mediumsamples = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({MediumSample(dictionary: $0.data())})

                        //fill the tableView
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            print(self.mediumsamples)
                        }

                        print("Mediums List", self.mediumsamples) // This line returns: Mediums List []

                        print("Mediums List size", (self.mediumsamples.count)) // This line returns: Mediums List size 0

                        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())") // This line returns the snapshot documents correctly!

                        }
                       }
               }
    }
```

Here is how the screenshot object object is added:

```
    func addMediumSamples() {

        let currentDateTime = Date()
        let location = FirebaseFirestore.GeoPoint(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
        let mediumsample = MediumSample(id: "an id", field_t: "field_t", field_i: 10, field_b1: true, field_b2: false, field_g: location, field_d: currentDateTime, field_a: [Constants.SAMPLE_DEV], usecase: Constants.SAMPLE_DEV)

        var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
        ref = self.db.collection(Constants.MEDIUMS).addDocument(data: mediumsample.dictionary) {
            error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error writing city to Firestore: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Document added with id : \(ref!.documentID)")
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: As you said it looks like your conversion is always returning nil. Can you screenshot one of your Firebase objects in Firebase console.

Comment: Hi Luka, I created an object and added and a screenshot above (in the first sentence). I also added the function I used. This object is created successfully but is still not returned in querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the **MediumSample struct**, in the **field_d** type (Date).
The type of that field in your Cloud Firestore database is **Timestamp**.

The field **"field_d"** in the MediumSample struct expects a value of type **Date**.

You can change the type to the **FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp**, or you can convert it to **Date** when mapping and before passing to the MediumSample.

eg. for converting Timestamp to Date in Swift

> let date = timestamp.dateValue()

Comment: Yes, thank very much. I was about entering this solution. I found it out by debugging the init dictionary function and I seen that type Date always causes interruption returning nil.