# How to retrieve data in array from Cloud Firebase in Swift UI?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I want to get the array from the data in firebase. My struct is as follows... How can I reach the goodFeeling and badFeelings datas through my path. I also want to so into my struct so that I can use them in my view.

```
struct Lokasyon: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable{

@DocumentID var id: String?
var cityName: String
var districtName: String
var cityId: Int?
var districtId: Int?
var goodFeelings: Int
var badFeelings: Int

}
struct FourthView: View {

@State var lokasyon = [Lokasyon]()
@State var name : String


var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        ForEach(lokasyon) {i in
            VStack{
                    
                    Text(i.cityName)
                
                    
                    Text(i.districtName)
                }
            
            
            HStack{
                VStack{
                    Image("smile")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    Text("\(i.goodFeelings)")
                    Text("Feeling Good")
                }
                
                VStack{
                    Image("sad")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    Text("\(i.badFeelings)")
                    Text("Feeling Bad")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }.onAppear(perform: newFunction)
    
    
}


 func newFunction() {

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let docRef = db.collection("posts").whereField("cityName", isEqualTo: name)


    docRef.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
          print("No documents")
          return
        }
        self.lokasyon = documents.compactMap { (QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> Lokasyon? in
            return try? QueryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Lokasyon.self)
        }
        print(self.lokasyon)
      }


    }
}
```

My firestore side is as follows. [image]

I want to retrieve and store that information to my struct, but could not do it. For example I want to display the goodFeelings' count and cityName in the path of "posts">"Mersin">Gülnar.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You did not say which part of your code doesn't work.

Comment: newFunction() is not working as I expected. Could not get the structure related to the arrays in documents.

Comment: I could find a similar issue on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681034/why-converting-a-firestore-querysnapshot-into-custom-objects-with-compactmap-ret) But I think it would be to know what is getting to you and to debug your program, this way we would know what is being returned to you (maybe a nil?)

Comment: Yes, I have an empty array returning